# Firebase : How to add new attribute in existing table

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on a project in swift and having firebase as backend for managing data.

```
FirebaseApp.configure()
Database.database().isPersistenceEnabled = true
```

This is what I have set in app delegate file. Now in my chat module, I have added message information in firebase database through below code.

```
    let messageData = ["text": text, "senderId": senderId, "senderName": senderDisplayName, "MediaType": "TEXT"]
    self.messageSentRef?.child("Messages").childByAutoId().setValue(messageData)
```

Now I want to add one new attribute named TimeStamp in messages table.

Anyone can help me how to do that?

Comment: Do you want to update already existing nodes? or just in new ones?

Comment: There are no tables in Firebase, only nodes (parent and child nodes). If you want to write to a new node it would be childNode.setValue("timestamp"). childNode would be defined in code as parentNode.child("child_node") or in your case messagesSentRef.child("Messages").childByAutoId().setValue("timestamp")

Answer (score 1):

If you have a MessageItem/MessageData object, you can always add more properties to that by modify your object structure. In order to add `timestamp` to the existing data, you can add it directly in your Firebase/Database console (which is a manual way to do it, or just do it in code like this)

```
let messageItem = MessageItem(text: text,
                           senderId: self.user.email,
                           senderDisplayName: false,
                           mediaType: "", 
                           timestamp: "")

let messageItemRef = self.ref.child("Message")
messageItemRef.setValue(messageItem.toAnyObject())
```

**Edit:**
The original question does not have a MessageItem object so let's put one together that makes this answer work:

In your viewController class (or whatever the top level class is) we need to implement a MessageItem class object like this

```
class MessageItem {
    var text = ""
    var senderId = ""
    var senderDisplayName = false
    var mediaType = ""
    var timestamp = ""

    init(text: String, senderId: String, senderDisplayName: Bool, mediaType: String, timestamp: String) {
        self.text = text
        self.senderId = senderId
        self.senderDisplayName = senderDisplayName
        self.mediaType = mediaType
        self.timestamp = timestamp
    }

    func toAnyObject() -> Any {
        return [
            "text": text,
            "senderId": senderId,
            "senderDisplayName": senderDisplayName,
            "mediaType": mediaType,
            "timestamp": timestamp
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a good answer but assumes the OP is using a class object. I added that functionality to your answer for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

In Firebase, data can be represented by a dictionary of key:value pairs. The key is always a string, but the value can be a number of different things, a String, Int etc.

The value can also be another dictionary of key: value pairs.

In your case, this line of code generates a key: value pair of a string: and another string (messsageData)

> self.messageSentRef?.child("Messages").childByAutoId().setValue(messageData)

which looks like this

```
app_node
   Messages
      -y88hj3-39i9isdf: "some message data"
```

If you want to also have a timestamp child, instead of writing the single string, you can write an entire dictionary of key: value pairs - like this

```
let messageDictionary = [
   "text": "some text",
   "senderId": "the sender Id",
   "senderDisplayName": "the sender display name",
   "mediaType": "a media type",
   "timestamp": "170708"
]

let messageItemRef = self.ref.child("Messages")
messageItemRef.childByAutoId().setValue(messageDictionary)
```

which creates the following node:

```
app_node
   Messages
      -Y9js9s9m494jms:
          text: "some text"
          senderId: "the sender Id"
          senderDisplayName: "the sender display name"
          mediaType: "a media type"
          timestamp: :170708"
```